# Двенадцать скамеек или скамейки?

Tags: морфология

Как правильно сказать: "В парке стояло двенадцать деревянных скамеек или скамейки"?
И это предложение в каком падеже?

Comment: Падеж - не свойство предложения. Это форма имен - существительных, прилагательных, местоимений.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: одиннадцать (12, 13, 40, 100) деревянн**ых** скаме**ек**. Это родительный падеж множественного числа. 
Определяющим признаком является последняя цифра, однако числительные от 11 до 14 хотя и заканчиваются на 1..4, требуют множественного числа, как и все числительные, заканчивающиеся на 5..9. Это связано с особенностью их названий, они заканчиваются на "дцать", что соответствует числу 10.

Answer (score 1):

Числительные 11, 12, 13, 14 не являются составными (это одно слово), в отличие от составных, оканчивающихся на 1, 2, 3, 4 (два и более слов - 24, 7562), поэтому существительные после них стоят во множественном числе в родительном падеже. Подлежащее в данном предложении выражено словосочетанием "двенадцать скамеек", где главное слово "двенадцать" стоит в именительном падеже, как и положено подлежащему. (Думаю, что Вы имели ввиду подлежащее, спрашивая "*И это предложение в каком падеже?*")

Answer (score 0):

При числительных два, три, четыре и в в конструкциях с составными числительными, оканчивающимися на два, три, четыре существительное пишется в родительном падеже единственного числа: два стола, но пять столов. 22 (53, 84)стола, но 25 (38, 99) столов. Так что 12 (11, 13, 20) деревянных скамеек.